# python django framewExpected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`

Tags: python, django

```
def post(self,request):
    try:
        profile_image=request.FILES['profile_image']
    except:
        profile_image=""

    full_name=request.data.get('full_image')
    email=request.data.get('email')
    mobile_number=request.data.get('mobile_number')
    gender=request.data.get('gender')

    print(is_alcoholic)
    dob=request.data.get('dob')
    country=request.data.get('country')
    state=request.data.get('state')
    city=request.data.get('city')
```

Answer (score 1):

Python functions return `None` if they don't execute a `return something` statement to return `something`.

This view falls off the end and returns `None` by default

Commonly  one returns a [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect), to specify what the browser next shows the user.